# Any way to get the console run as a tab in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In Eclipse, when a program is run the output is displayed in a tab in the bottom portion of the screen. Is there any way to do this in Visual Studio?

For example if my program prints `Hello World` I want it to show `Hello World` in some sort of console tab instead of opening up in a totally different window.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio also have `Output Panel`, where you can view debug process and console output etc.

you can access this from View `Menu -> Output` or `Debug Menu -> Windows -> Output`. Debug menu will let you to see the printed console output while you are debugging or running the program.

or using keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>.

To print some thing in output windows use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` or  `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write()` methods.

[image: output window]

Comment: I see the Output Panel but I don't see anything in there that the program has printed. For example if my program prints `Hello World` I want it to show `Hello World` in some sort of console tab instead of opening up in a totally different window.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Debug -> Windows -> Output

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine method.